# Ant execute arbitrary programs and terminate at end of junit task

Tags: java, ant, junit, rmi

I am attempting to write unit tests against a series of RMI interfaces / implementations and am relying on Ant + Junit to facilitate these tests.  The main problem is that I need to have the `rmiregistry` start up at the beginning of my Junit task and close down at the end of execution whether that be failure,error, or success.   Ant script:

```
<project>
    <target name="test">  
      <javac srcdir="Test/src" destdir="Test/bin" />  
      <junit fork="true" printsummary="true">  
          <batchtest>   
             <fileset dir="Test/test">  
                 <include name="**/*Test.*"/>  
             </fileset> 
          </batchtest>  
      </junit>  
    </target>  
</project>
```

Comment: Do you basically know how to startup and close the registry?

Comment: @oers yes `start rmiregistry` from the command line.  To close the registry I terminate the process.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just set `haltonerror="false"` and `failonerror="false`"  for the junit task.
This way `junit` won't fail due to tests.  Starting and stopping is done via the [exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html). I used taskkill here to kill the rmiregistry.exe.

```
<exec executable="start"> <--your start command here -->
  <arg value="rmiregistry"/>
</exec>
<junit fork="true" printsummary="true" haltonerror="false" failonerror="false" errorproperty="juniterrors" failureproperty="junitfailures"> 
  ...
</junit>
<exec executable="taskkill"> <--your shutdown command here -->
  <arg value="/IM"/>
  <arg value="rmiregistry.exe"/>
</exec>
<fail if="juniterrors"/> <!-- ant can fail now, if desired -->
<fail if="junitfailures"/>
```

Another option is to use [try/catch from ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html), but I don't think this is needed here.